# How can I configure the Xserver config file

Tags: ati, xorg, configuration, xserver

I recently purchased an AMD R9 280 and I want to integrate it in my system. It seems like I have to cofigure the Xserver so how can I do that. I already createt the config file in the root shell but when I enter this command: `gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` to open it in **gedit** my **PC crashes**. Then I tried to open it in **nano** (that is an editor without gui) like that: `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and it showed that it had opened it but it was empty, **no text appared**. **What did I do wrong?**

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-Bit.

Answer (score 0):

First install the AMD driver if you have not, then ope the control center.

I dont have a AMD handy but somewhere you will have an option like "save to X config file"

If you dont mind using Terminal just type

```
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

This should make one at etc/x11/xorg.conf you can then use nano or Gedit or whatever to open it.
The followig site has very detailed info about AMD video drivers.

[AND Binary config page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)

If you need drivers go to dash and search for software sources and choose the additional drivers tab.

EDIT....

First remove your driver

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

And install this one

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

If it fails install this and try again

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

DO NOT REBOOT

Then try `sudo amdconfig --initial`

Comment: When I ran `sudo amdconfig --initial` it did not know the command "amdconfig".

Comment: Ok, `sudo amdconfig --initial` ran fine afterwards but when I tried `gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` my PC began to slow down same as before (so slow the cursor did not move when it should) and I shut it down with the power button, same as before. But **now I can´t get it to restart**!!! Everything goes well until I get to booting ubuntu. The Ubuntu load screen seems to stay there for longer than usual and when the lock screen is supposed to open the screen just goes black. What have I done wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please follow the instructions in the following site-  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode   -to boot to recovery mode (don't forget to mount /root as read/write) open terminal and use the following command to delete xorg.conf   sudo rm etc/x11/xorg.conf        then reboot see if this fixes you boot issue, let me know

Comment: It puts out the error that it can´t be deleted because it is not found. I tried booting again though, and it just froze at the loading screen.

Comment: What cant be deleted ? We are trying to install not delete

Comment: When using the command `rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` that you proposed in the root shell, it put out the error: **file or directory cannot be removed because it is not found**.

Comment: Sorry I got confused with another question. Did you try recovery mode ? Did it work ? Did you have a graphical shell ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16615/discussion-between-ubuntu-stuff-and-mark-kirby).